# Django forms keyerror on ModelChoiceField

Tags: django, forms

I have a form used for advanced searching. One of the fields, `island_group` is a ModelChoiceField for which I am returning a `values_list` as the queryset (so as to get each distinct value only once).

**forms.py:**

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    ...
    island_group = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        required=False,
        queryset=Locality.objects.values_list('islandgroup', flat=True).distinct('islandgroup')
    ...
```

and because this throws an error along the lines of `invalid choice` because I'm using the values rather than the objects, I override the error:

```
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(SearchForm, self).clean()

        if self._errors["island_group"]:
            del self._errors["island_group"]

        return cleaned_data
```

However, I keep getting `KeyError at /collections/ 'island_group'` errors. In fact as this data is being pulled from a read-only database, I just want to be able to pass it into the views with minimum fuss.

Any help would be much appreciated. Also, here is the traceback:

```
Traceback:
File "/home/sam/django-projects/datazone/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/sam/django-projects/datazone/bin/datazone/cdrs/views.py" in cdrs_index
  59.     return render(request, 'cdrs_index.html', context)    
File "/home/sam/django-projects/datazone/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py" in render
  44.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs),
File "/home/sam/django-projects/datazone/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  188.         return t.render(context_instance)
File "/home/sam/django-projects/datazone/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  123.             return self._render(context)
File "/home/sam/django-projects/datazone/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/utils.py" in instrumented_test_render
  57.     return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/sam/django-projects/datazone/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  744.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
File "/home/sam/django-projects/datazone/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_node
  757.         return node.render(context)
File "/home/sam/django-projects/datazone/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  127.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/home/sam/django-projects/datazone/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/utils.py" in instrumented_test_render
  57.     return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/sam/django-projects/datazone/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  744.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
File "/home/sam/django-projects/datazone/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_node
  757.         return node.render(context)
File "/home/sam/django-projects/datazone/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  64.             result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/sam/django-projects/datazone/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  744.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
File "/home/sam/django-projects/datazone/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_node
  757.         return node.render(context)
File "/home/sam/django-projects/datazone/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  227.                 nodelist.append(node.render(context))
File "/home/sam/django-projects/datazone/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  792.             output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
File "/home/sam/django-projects/datazone/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in resolve
  510.                 obj = self.var.resolve(context)
File "/home/sam/django-projects/datazone/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in resolve
  653.             value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
File "/home/sam/django-projects/datazone/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _resolve_lookup
  683.                         current = getattr(current, bit)
File "/home/sam/django-projects/datazone/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _errors
  415.         return self.form.errors.get(self.name, self.form.error_class())
File "/home/sam/django-projects/datazone/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _get_errors
  112.             self.full_clean()
File "/home/sam/django-projects/datazone/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in full_clean
  268.         self._clean_form()
File "/home/sam/django-projects/datazone/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _clean_form
  296.             self.cleaned_data = self.clean()
File "/home/sam/django-projects/datazone/bin/datazone/cdrs/forms.py" in clean
  113.         if self._errors["island_group"]:

Exception Type: KeyError at /collections/
Exception Value: 'island_group'
```

Answer (score 0):

*update*

I think I know your exception, it might look like `Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.` right?
The reason is that `Locality.objects.values_list('islandgroup', flat=True).distinct('islandgroup')` which you passed to `queryset=`, is `ValuesListQuerySet` instead of `QuerySet`. The `ValueListQuerySet` instance does not contain `_meta` info and is used as normal list, this causes `ModelChoiceField` to generate incorrect form options. Just like the contrived example below

```
>>> from django import forms
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import *

>>> class F(forms.Form):
...     user = forms.ModelChoiceForm(queryset=User.objects.values_list('username', flat=True))

>>> print F().as_p()
<p><label for="id_user">User:</label> <select name="user" id="id_user">
<option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
<option value="okm">okm</option>
</select></p>
```

However, the correct value of the second option should be `pk` of user okm, just like

```
>>> class F(forms.Form):
...     user = forms.ModelChoiceForm(queryset=User.objects)

>>> print F().as_p()
<p><label for="id_user">User:</label> <select name="user" id="id_user">
<option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
<option value="1">okm</option>
</select></p>
```

Thus you need to change the `island_group =` line in your code, according to the type of the `islandgroup` model field.

Except the above issue, you code is fine. Thus when there is no other `'island_group'` validation errors in `self._errors`, `self._errors["island_group"]` raises the KeyError.

Comment: So the `invalid choice` error pops up when I remove my custom clean method. If nothing is selected in the field then the field passes validation, bu as soon as I select something then the error is raised. I'm guess this is because these are string values and not objects? So basically I just need Django to stop failing me because of they are not objects, and the custom clean method was the best I came up with. I'm not sure I understand your third paragraph - why is checking for the existence of `self._errors["island_group"]`  raising a KeyError?

Comment: @DarwinTech I mean the `KeyError` is a Python exception just as the exception raised by `{}['key']`. You could avoid it by `{}.get('key')` or `if 'key' in {}: {}['key']`

Comment: OK. This works with the custom clean method: `if "island_group" in self._errors: del self._errors["island_group"]`. I would like to post the stacktrace of the `invalid choice` validation error - how do I access it when Django doesn't fail (it just returns me that error)?